Need help for resolving RAML error - ClassCastException
I am new RAML and I am writing api.raml with types.
While RAML verification I am getting below error -
For raml specification am getting ClassCastException. Actually I have json like below -
{ 
“content”:[
    “nodeType”:”paragraph”,
    “content”:[]
]
}

I have added RAML specification like
content:
   type: array
   minItems: 0
   maxItems: 100
   properties:
      nodeType:
         type: string
      content:
          type: contentType

    contentType:
        type: object
        additionalProperties: false
        properties: 
           nodeType:
              type: string
       content:
          type: contentType

